# extremely high categorical accuracy keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to train a CNN classifier to perform image classification among seven classes of images.  Naively, I would expect the algorithm to produce ~20% accuracy on early epochs of training, but it is in the ~40% accuracy range, which leads me to the conclusion that somehow my model isn't properly calculating categorical accuracy.  What am I doing wrong?

```py
import glob

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.metrics import top_k_categorical_accuracy

# Define Constants
img_height = 299
img_width = 299

batch_size=40
epochs=30

train_data_dir="./train/"
validate_data_dir="./validate/"
test_data_dir="./test/"

nb_train_samples=len(glob.glob(train_data_dir+"**/*.jpg"))
nb_validation_samples= len(glob.glob(validate_data_dir+"**/*.jpg"))
nb_test_samples= len(glob.glob(test_data_dir+"**/*.jpg"))

# Define CNN Layers
if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))

def top_2_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=2) 

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['categorical_accuracy', top_2_categorical_accuracy])

# Train Datagen
print("\nInitializing Training Data Generator:")
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')
print("")

# Validation Datagen
print("Initializing Validation Data Generator:")
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
valid_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validate_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')
print("")

# Test Datagen
print("Initializing Test Data Generator:")
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')
print("")

# Run
print("Starting Training...")
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=valid_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size,
    verbose=2)
print("Done!\n\n")

# Save Weights
model.save('model.h5')

# Evaluate
print("Starting Testing...")
print("[Loss, Percent Error]")
model.evaluate_generator(test_generator)
```

Here is the output:

```js
Using TensorFlow backend.

Initializing Training Data Generator:
Found 5600 images belonging to 7 classes.

Initializing Validation Data Generator:
Found 700 images belonging to 7 classes.

Initializing Test Data Generator:
Found 700 images belonging to 7 classes.

Starting Training...
Epoch 1/30
 - 58s - loss: 1.8719 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2279 - top_2_categorical_accuracy: 0.4107 - val_loss: 1.8315 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.2809 - val_top_2_categorical_accuracy: 0.4456
Epoch 2/30
 - 53s - loss: 1.7584 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2913 - top_2_categorical_accuracy: 0.4714 - val_loss: 1.6551 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3485 - val_top_2_categorical_accuracy: 0.5559
Epoch 3/30
 - 53s - loss: 1.6987 - categorical_accuracy: 0.3166 - top_2_categorical_accuracy: 0.5150 - val_loss: 1.6445 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3897 - val_top_2_categorical_accuracy: 0.5735
Epoch 4/30
 - 53s - loss: 1.6495 - categorical_accuracy: 0.3407 - top_2_categorical_accuracy: 0.5418 - val_loss: 1.5398 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3868 - val_top_2_categorical_accuracy: 0.6029
Epoch 5/30
 - 53s - loss: 1.5844 - categorical_accuracy: 0.3687 - top_2_categorical_accuracy: 0.5729 - val_loss: 1.5124 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.4162 - val_top_2_categorical_accuracy: 0.5985
Epoch 6/30
 - 53s - loss: 1.4989 - categorical_accuracy: 0.4075 - top_2_categorical_accuracy: 0.6132 - val_loss: 1.5065 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3956 - val_top_2_categorical_accuracy: 0.6029
Epoch 7/30
 - 53s - loss: 1.4233 - categorical_accuracy: 0.4314 - top_2_categorical_accuracy: 0.6416 - val_loss: 1.4560 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.4618 - val_top_2_categorical_accuracy: 0.6441
Epoch 8/30
 - 53s - loss: 1.3212 - categorical_accuracy: 0.4754 - top_2_categorical_accuracy: 0.6770 - val_loss: 1.4556 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.4324 - val_top_2_categorical_accuracy: 0.6309
Epoch 9/30
 - 53s - loss: 1.2623 - categorical_accuracy: 0.4993 - top_2_categorical_accuracy: 0.7055 - val_loss: 1.5422 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.4397 - val_top_2_categorical_accuracy: 0.6279
Epoch 10/30
```

Comment: What makes you think anything is wrong? The 20% you expect seems to be just a random number.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this was occurring was two-fold:

1. Using `steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size` meant that it would only see the entire set after `batch_size` epochs.
2. The `shuffle` option was not set.

As a result, the model was learning to vote for some given class. While this isn't an 'error' so to speak, it is concerning for the accuracy to be so high at the end of an epoch.

Comment: I don't think your first reason is correct. Exactly `steps * batch_size = samples // batch_size * batch_size ~= samples` samples will be yielded by the Iterator during an epoch. If `batch_size` is a factor of `samples`, all samples will be seen. If not, then only the last batch (with smaller size than `batch_size`) will not be seen, and will be the first retrieved in the next epoch. See [Iterator#L1042](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L1042)'s implementation.